# Why asyncpg connection pool works slower than just connections

Tags: python, postgresql, python-asyncio, asyncpg

I have two postgres cliets and both of them use **asyncpg**. First creates new connection for each request, second use pool of connections.

Fist:

```py
class PostgresConnection(object):
    def __init__(self, conn) -> None:
        self.conn: asyncpg.Connection = conn

    @classmethod
    async def get_connection(cls) -> asyncpg.Connection:
        conn = await asyncpg.connect(
            user='',
            password='',
            database=''
            host='',
            port=,
        )
        return cls(conn)

    async def execute(self, query: str) -> None:
        return await self.conn.execute(query)

    async def fetch_all(self, query: str) -> list[asyncpg.Record | None]:
        return await self.conn.fetch(query)
```

Second:

```py
class PostgresConnection:
    def __init__(
        self,
        DSN: str = DSN,
    ):
        self.DSN = DSN
        self.con = None
        self._cursor = None
        self._connection_pool = None

    async def create_pool(self) -> None:
        self._connection_pool = await asyncpg.create_pool(
            dsn=self.DSN,
        )

    async def get_pool(self) -> Pool:
        if not self._connection_pool:
            await self.create_pool()
        return self._connection_pool

    async def fetch_all(self, query: str) -> list[dict | None]:
        pool = await self.get_pool()
        async with pool.acquire() as conn:
            return [dict(row) for row in await conn.fetch(query)]
```

And i maked simple test: make 100 times 'SELECT * FROM user'

**fist: 5sec**

```py
conn = await PostgresClient.get_connection()
for i in range(1_00):
   await conn.fetch_all('SELECT * FROM "user"')
```

**second: 10sec**

```py
pg_conn = PostgresConnection()
for i in range(1_00):
   await pg_conn.fetch_all('SELECT * FROM "user"')
```

In one of the tests i used max size of pool = 100 and check how many connections was used — it was 16/17 (i checked ID of connections which pool returns). But i think thats not important in my case and i just did something wrong.

Why connection pool works 2x times slower? Is the problem on db side ?

Comment: Hard to say. I imagine that as each connection in the pool is acquired, or let-go, either the driver or the DB issues some state-reset statements for that connection, which end up taking as much time as the simple select you are making. If so, the pool might be more useful if more statements are executed each time a connection is acquired.